# How to use std::chrono::milliseconds as a default parameter

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono, milliseconds

**Scenario**
I have a C++ function which intakes a parameter as `std::chrono::milliseconds`. It is basically a timeout value. And, it is a default parameter set to some value by default.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

void Fun(const std::chrono::milliseconds someTimeout = std::chrono::milliseconds(100)) {
    if (someTimeout > 0) {
        std::cout << "someNumberInMillis is: " << someNumberInMillis.count() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned int someValue = 500;
    Fun(std::chrono::milliseconds(someValue))
}
```

**Issue**
All of above is okay but, when I call `Fun` with a value then fails to compile and I get the following error:

> No viable conversion from 'bool' to 'std::chrono::milliseconds' (aka
>   'duration >')

**Question:**
What am I doing wrong here? I want the caller of `Fun` to be explicitly aware that it is using `std::chrono::milliseconds` when it invokes `Fun`. But the compiler doesn't seem to allow using `std::chrono::milliseconds` as a parameter?

How use `std::chrono::milliseconds` as a default parameter?

**Environment**
Compiler used is clang on macOS High Sierra

Comment: `if (someTimeout > 0)`?  My compiler can't find a matching overload for that.  And where does `someNumberInMillis` come from?  When I fix those and the other obvious syntax errors, compiles fine for me on GCC9.

Comment: I updated the code. Please check again. I was improving the variables name :-D

Comment: It compiles with gcc?? Amazing! I am using clang as the compiler on macOS. I updated the environment details on the question

Comment: As I said, I had to fix a few of the syntax errors, namely the inconsistent names, comparison against integer and missing semicolon.  Can you update to a [mcve] that doesn't have any errors other than the one we're interested in?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the other syntax errors fixed, this compiles without warnings in GCC 9:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

void Fun(const std::chrono::milliseconds someNumberInMillis
                                         = std::chrono::milliseconds(100))
{
    if (someNumberInMillis > std::chrono::milliseconds{0}) {
        std::cout << "someNumberInMillis is: " << someNumberInMillis.count()
                  << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int someValue = 500;
    Fun(std::chrono::milliseconds(someValue));
}
```

Comment: Extremely sorry. I accept. I was different mistake :-(. This question could still be useful for newbies looking to know how to use a chrono type as a parameter. Thanks to you.